# Spring Data JDBC: Conversion of compound domain types

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

After listening to a nice talk about Spring Data JDBC and Doamin-Driven Design by Jens Schauder (as an AFOL I love your examples;-) I experimented a bit but get stuck quite soon with my domain types. Of course I need to write custom JDBC converters, for example to map a TelephoneNumber to String and back, but how do I handle more complex types like a period which has a LocalDate as start date and a LocalDate as end date. Or an address with street, house no, zip code, city...

I can not add annotations to these types, because the can have a different meaning depending on their use, for example an invoice address vs. a delivery address.

Using JPA/Hibernate a can use `@Columns` or `@AttributeOverrides` or implement a compound hibernate user type, but in Spring Data JDBC a found only simple converters.

Do I missed something or is this not (yet) possible with Spring Data JDBC?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the `@Embedded` annotation.
It is available in the 1.1.x versions. 
Using that (and Lombok to keep the code short) you can model a `Period` like this:

```
@Value
class Period {
    LocalDate from;
    LocalDate until;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
@Value
class SpecialOffer {
     String name;
     int rebate;

     @Embedded(onEmpty = OnEmpty.USE_EMPTY, prefix="valid_")
     Period valid;
}
```

This will map the object to a single table `SPECIAL_OFFER` with the columns `NAME`, `REBATE`, `VALID_FROM`, `VALID_UNTIL`

There is currently no way to specify a `Converter` for a single attribute only. 
The way to work around that would be to create a wrapper around the value and create a converter for that.